# How to make row editor visible all the time in extJS roweditor

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

How to make row editor visible all the time in extJS roweditor..

I am using extJS grid and row ediotr pluing in the grid. I want to make my row editor visible all the time.

1. Currently it happening when I am clicking into the row/cell.

I want overide activateCell as soon as I load the gridso it become visible in grid. Any solution for this. I am overiding the grid plugin.

Comment: I have no solution for you, but I think the better way in you case just add some css styles to cell - may be border like when you edit field. Because in my practice, overriding in ExtJS sometimes get surprices. What type of your editor field (text, checkbox, other)?

Comment: @V.Tur I am using all editor like number, combo, text. Only thing this is getting activated only while clicking on cell. so I want to visisble all the time. Can u help what css shall I use.

Comment: I added style example, and try to find something more in my previous projects

Answer (score 1):

You can try aplly something like:

```
gridcolumn:
{
    text: 'Some Text', 
    dataIndex: 'Color',
    renderer: function (value, meta) {
        meta.style = 'border: 1px solid grey;';
        return value;
    },
    editor: {
      xtype: 'textfield
    } 
}
```

Great article about grid styles: http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells

Comment: correct this but  can I give tis at plugin level, so I no need  configure each time in my column.

Comment: see please link, and I think you will can add some classes to whole grid for cells

Comment: Thanks for this article, I am able to do it only have an issue with the diffrent cls styls for combo, textfield and numberfield.